# How to configure Git on my local machine?

Tags: git

I have a git repository locally on the machine and would now like to sync my current project from the same machine to it. Unfortunately this does not work.

I have created a repository under `/home/git/`.

```sh
mkdir climhost.git
chown -R git:git climhost.git/
cd climhost.git/
git init --bare
```

then I wanted to map the repository from the project folder, so I ran the following in the project folder.

```sh
git init
git remote add origin user@localhost/home/git/climahost.git
git add .
git commit -am "initial commit"
git push origin master:master
```

But then I get the following error message:

```
fatal: 'rese@localhost/home/git/climahost.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
What am I doing wrong? does anyone have a tip for me?

Comment: Is localhost/home/git a valid path?

Comment: If it's on the same machine, you almost certainly don't need `user@localhost`.  The simple file path `/home/git/climhost.git` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You set

```
mkdir climhost.git
```

Then

```
git remote add origin user@localhost/home/git/climahost.git
```

There is a typo: `climhost` VS `climahost`